# ZPL2: adjust label width

Tags: zpl, epl

I'm trying to migrate a simple label from EPL2 to ZPL2 and I'm having some issues adjusting the label width and its top position. With EPL2, we cou use the `Q` and `q` commands for setting the label's height, gap and width. I've tried using `^ML` and `^LL` but it does not work. Here's the demo text I'm sending to the printer:

```
^XA
^SZ2
^CI13
^ML416
^LH0,0
^FO40,30^ACN,18,10^FDGRM^FS^FO180,30^ACN,18,10^FDTAG0000026942^FS^FO40,53^BQN,2,2,M,7^FDQA,https://hardwareinfo.madeira.gov.pt/?tag=TAG0000026942^FS
^FO170,53^BEN,100,Y,N^FD0001231231232^FS
^PON^PQ1
^XZ
```

Unfortunately, it's still using the size of the previously printed label (everything is moved to the left)...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to my own question, it's the `PW` command...